# com.itextpdf:book:war:5.3.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved:

Tags: java, maven

I work on this demo project http://itextpdf.com/download.php when i try to build my api i have this error message (dependencies).

```
Failed to execute goal on project book: Could not resolve dependencies for project   
com.itextpdf:book:war:5.3.1-SNAPSHOT: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.3.1-SNAPSHOT, 
com.itextpdf:itext-xtra:jar:5.3.1-SNAPSHOT, 
com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:jar:5.3.1-SNAPSHOT, 
itext-pdfa:com.itextpdf:jar:5.3.1-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not find artifact com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.3.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: Make sure to add the repositories for all of the libraries you're using as dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a SNAPSHOT version, it *may not* be available for download.  You could use the [5.3.0 version](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.itextpdf%22%20AND%20a%3a%22itextpdf%22) which is available from maven central.